# Eclipse console maven output not showing after app is ran

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-plugin, exec-maven-plugin

Usually when you run a maven build in eclipse, it will show the results of each phase in the console in eclipse, and end with a big FAILURE or SUCCESS output.

But when I run an application in one of the build phases as part of my maven build, I see the maven output up until the application is running and then I see the application is starting up but no maven output after that.

Is it in a different console?

I want to start an application, and then in my `integration-test`phase, run the integration tests that use the running app.

here is the output I am seeing:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building UserRegistrationServices 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ rest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ rest ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ rest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\pmandayam\git\UserRegistrationServices\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ rest ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ rest ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:java (my-execution) @ rest ---
[WARNING] Warning: killAfter is now deprecated. Do you need it ? Please comment on MEXEC-6.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.5.RELEASE)

Aug 04, 2015 3:45:38 PM org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger logStarting
INFO: Starting Application on CNU43390VX with PID 21300 (C:\Users\pmandayam\git\UserRegistrationServices\target\classes started by pmandayam in C:\Users\pmandayam\git\UserRegistrationServices)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:38 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2e500635: startup date [Tue Aug 04 15:45:38 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:39 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:40 PM org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f7e4d7] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:40 PM org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:40 PM org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@6539808b' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:40 PM org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b3d61949] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:40 PM org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:40 PM org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'metaDataSourceAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:40 PM org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer initialize
INFO: Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:41 PM org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext prepareEmbeddedWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2808 ms
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain <init>
INFO: Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2bfb02e5, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@b88096f, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@213e002f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@67a54cef, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@4e56549f, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@750fdc80, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7d01d0d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@533cd22b, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6d1025ca, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@684e40c9, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3140fe28]
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean onStartup
INFO: Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean configure
INFO: Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean configure
INFO: Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean configure
INFO: Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration$DefaultInMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer configure
INFO: 

Using default security password: bf87906c-265c-4f62-baae-cdc80c66fc46

Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2e500635: startup date [Tue Aug 04 15:45:38 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/users/register],methods=[POST]}" onto public main.User main.UserRestController.register(main.User)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/users/update],methods=[PUT]}" onto public main.User main.UserRestController.update(java.lang.String,main.User)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/users/get/ByAddress],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<main.ReturnedUser> main.UserRestController.getByAddress(java.lang.String)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/users/getBasicUser],methods=[GET]}" onto public main.User main.UserRestController.getBasicUser(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/users/get/AllUsers],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<main.ReturnedUser> main.UserRestController.getAllUsers()
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/users/get/ByFullName],methods=[GET]}" onto public main.ReturnedUser main.UserRestController.getByFullName(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/users/get/ByUsername],methods=[GET]}" onto public main.ReturnedUser main.UserRestController.getByUsername(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/users/get/ByEmail],methods=[GET]}" onto public main.ReturnedUser main.UserRestController.getByEmail(java.lang.String)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/users/get/ByPhoneNumber],methods=[GET]}" onto public main.ReturnedUser main.UserRestController.getByPhoneNumber(java.lang.String)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/users/get/ByFirstname],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<main.ReturnedUser> main.UserRestController.getByFirstname(java.lang.String)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/users/get/ByLastname],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<main.ReturnedUser> main.UserRestController.getByLastname(java.lang.String)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/users/get/ByZipCode],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<main.ReturnedUser> main.UserRestController.getByZipCode(java.lang.String)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/users/get/ByCity],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<main.ReturnedUser> main.UserRestController.getByCity(java.lang.String)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/users/get/ByState],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<main.ReturnedUser> main.UserRestController.getByState(java.lang.String)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/users/login],methods=[POST]}" onto public main.RoleInfo main.UserRestController.login(main.Credentials)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/users/delete],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void main.UserRestController.deleteUser(java.util.List<java.lang.String>)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:44 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:44 PM org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter afterSingletonsInstantiated
INFO: Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:44 PM org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer start
INFO: Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
Aug 04, 2015 3:45:44 PM org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger logStarted
INFO: Started Application in 6.041 seconds (JVM running for 11.541)
```

EDIT: As per Nicoll's comment below, my maven build cannot find the start or stop goals and it is giving me an error that says it can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spring-boot:run` is actually holding the build thread while the app is running. If we didn't do that, the process would just die once your application has started.

If you want to configure your build for a typical integration test scenario, we've added that as of Spring 1.3, check [the updated documentation for more details](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M2/maven-plugin/usage.html) (see *Working with integration tests*)

Comment: Nicoll, now it is saying: "Could not find goal 'start' in plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE among available goals help, repackage, run ->".                   It can't find the goals start and stop.

Comment: I wrote "as of Spring 1.3" :-)

Comment: ahh I see my bad. Just one more question, is the latest version of the spring boot starter PARENT 1.2.5? Because I do not see anything past that in the maven repository

Comment: @Nicoll, nvm I see it in the milestone repository. Thanks a lot

Comment: Going [on the project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) should help as well. You can also create a sample project on the latest `1.3.0` milestone via https://start.spring.io

Comment: Was a quick fix and solved my problem. Thanks again.